# Is it possible to receive json objects partly from server specific to android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, json, afnetworking, retrofit

In my mobile app (android and iOS), I received a very big json (https://api.github.com/repositories) whole at once. So that my app becomes slower in working when on slow internet connection.

Is there any way or request for receiving json partwise from server? Means what I actually want is that I have total 100 objetcs. At first only 5 or 10 gets downloaded from server. Afterwards when I scroll down my app, next 5 or 10 objects downloaded. This way. So that my apps response time become less.

Comment: AFAIK there is a way, but it's not related with retrofit. It's the pagination feature where you specify a parameter ``since`` with the id of the last repository you've seen. You can then use the headers of the response to get the next batch of data - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories

Comment: yeah. thanks. This is the way. But it is applicable to only this github json on which you are talking about. But I am doing only demo king of app with this json. I am currently working on one app magzine where all backend code is already developed. At there, these guys are sending me whole json of magzine at one with single url. So I am thinking that if I can partly receive this json at my side, then it will be more beneficial.